# Do themes change the layout of the desktop on ubuntu?

Tags: themes

Question is same as title.

If I download different themes are they just backgrounds and colour combos or do they change the layout and working of the desktop like a launcher on my phone?

I have unity and have seen lots of different themes but do not know whether or not to download them if they are just colours and not changes of layouts.

Comment: No, what you need are desktop environments. Have a look at
http://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available

Answer (score 0):

No, the themes do not change the layout of Unity, GNOME, or KDE.